# What are the implications on prediction if a regression model with heteoscedastic errors is considered for analysis?

Tags: regression, least-squares, validation, breusch-pagan

I have a simple linear regression model, and I tried validating if the model fit for purposes.

One of the tests is Bruesch Pagan test on the residuals but the result of the test shows that the error term is heteroscedastic, if I continue using this model, what would be the implication to my prediction?

Comment: Since you are running a simple linear regression, then you could share a scatterplot here quite easily (along with plotted residuals) and that would give an idea of whether or not this matters.

Comment: As far as prediction goes, heteroscedasticity causes two main problems: (1) the predictions will be less accurate, compared to predictions obtained from properly weighted estimates, particularly in regions having smaller variance; and (2) the assessment of prediction accuracy, as measured by the usual rmse, will be wrong (too small in regions of high variance and too large in regions of low variance). Of course, whether these problems are sufficient to justify using some kind of (implicit or explicit) weighting depends on the severity of the heteroscedasticity.

Answer (score 2):

Limiting this question: if I continue using this [model that contains heteroskedasticity], what would be the implication to my prediction?

Heteroskedasticity has no effect on the unbiasedness or consistency of the OLS estimator and also has no effect on the r-squared or adjusted r-squared.

Where heteroskedasticity comes into play is in hypothesis testing. Under heteroskedasticity, the usual t statistics do not have t distributions, the usual F statistics do not have F distributions, and the usual LM statistic does not have an asymptotic chi-square distribution. Thus, heteroskedasticity invalidates the usual hypothesis testing.

In addition, it can be shown that heteroskedasticity renders OLS so that it is no longer BLUE (Best Linear Unbiased Estimator) and so that it is no longer asymptotically efficient among a certain class of estimators.

The good news is that the t, F, and LM statistics can be modified to be valid in the presence of heteroskedasticity of unknown form. Once the standard errors are made robust to heteroskedasticity, it is important to remember that they have only asymptotic justification.